# sed to extract lines following a starting group pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed

I currently ran into a problem that needs some help solving. Even pointing in the correct direction would help.

I have a file with lots of lines and want to extract only specific 'group' of lines if they are following a pattern. (Line has to start with `A`, next line has to start with `B`, next line has to start with `C`)

For example: Pattern: Starting with `A`, `B`, `C` in this order.

Input:

```
A1
B1
C1
D1
A2
B2
D2
A3
D3
A4
B4
C4
A5
B5
D5
```

Output:

```
A1
B1
C1
A4
B4
C4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would also like a Sed solution, this is ugly but should work.

```
sed -n '
  /^A/{
    N
    /\nB/!D
    N
    /\nC/!{
      s/\n//
      D
    }
    p
  }
' file
```

`-n` tells sed not to print anything unless it reaches the `p` command.

If you understand the first block, you can understand the rest:

- `/^A/` If pattern space starts with A,

  - `N` Append next line to pattern space.
  - `/\nB/!D` If pattern space does not have a newline followed by B, delete all up to the first newline and start again with the resulting pattern space and without reading any input.

One liner: `sed -n '/^A/{N;/\nB/!D;N;/\nC/!{s/\n//;D};p}' file`

Comment: I like this one the most since it is easily adjustable, readable and understandable. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution with `awk`:

```bsh
awk 'p2~/^A/ && p1~/^B/ && /^C/{print p2 RS p1 RS $0} {p2=p1; p1=$0}'
```

With `perl` and slurping entire input as single string:

```bsh
perl -0777 -ne 'print /^A.*\nB.*\nC.*\n/mg'
```

With [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which supports a handy multiline matching option `-U`

```bsh
rg -oUN '^A.*\nB.*\nC.*'
```

Here, `-o` option gets only matching portion and `-N` option is to prevent line numbers in output

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` program should work:

```
awk 's==2{if (/^C/) {s=0; p=p ORS $0; print p} else {s=0}}\
     s==1{if (/^B/) {s=2; p=p ORS $0} else {s=0}}\
     s==0{if (/^A/) {s=1; p=$0}}' input.txt
```

This will keep an internal "status" flag `s` to see at which point in the sequence we are (0: start not found, 1: `A` found, 2: `A` and `B` found in sequence), and accumulating the text in a buffer `p`.

- If `A` and `B` was found, and the current line starts with `C`, we add the current line to the buffer and print it. The status is reset to `0`
- If `A` was found, and the current line starts with `B`, we add the current line to the buffer and set the status to `2` (=`A` and `B` found)
- If the start was not yet found, and the current line starts with `A`, we add this to the buffer and set the status to `1`.

Comment: It works thank you. sed would be easier for me to process the rest but I can work with this.

Answer (score 1):

This relies on a multi-line pattern space and discards the top-most line as soon a match is not found and the search is then started over. Lines are added after each match. A group is fully matched when all pieces are matched in turn:

```
sed '/^A/!D; /\n/!N; /\nB/!D; N; /\nC/!D'
```

The solution can be generalised to match an arbitrary number of lines, and using a bit more care to isolate search terms. The script below will match a 4-line group (e.g. A|B|A|B), simply substitute successive lines for each "X":

```
sed '
    # If X does not begin pattern space, delete first line,
    # return to script start, read a line if none remain
    /^X/!D
    # Append next line if pattern space holds 1 line
    /\n/!N

    # If X does not begin line 2+ of pattern space, delete first line,
    # return to script start, read a line if none remain
    /\nX/!D
    # Append next line if pattern space holds < 3 lines
    /\n.*\n/!N

    # If X does not begin line 3+ of pattern space, delete first line,
    # return to script start, read a line if none remain
    /\n.*\nX/!D
    # Append next line if pattern space holds < 4 lines
    /\n.*\n.*\n/!N

    # If X does not begin line 4+ of pattern space, delete first line,
    # return to script start, read a line if none remain
    /\n.*\n.*\nX/!D

    # After here, output pattern space then discard and start again
'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can setup a state machine in sed to advance to the next state only if the previous state would lead you A->B->C

Otherwise, chop the head and restart.

```
$ sed -e '$d;/\n/d
    /^A/N;/\nB/!D
    $!N;/\nC/!D
' file
A1
B1
C1
A4
B4
C4
```

if you have gnu grep compiled with the PCRE option, then the following grep code
Is another way.

```
$ grep -zoP '(?m)^A.*\nB.*\nC.*\n' file | tr -d '\0'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Pugged the leak now.it would not have printed `A1|B2|C1 but B1|B2|C1`

Comment: You are welcome! But I'm afraid that Sed still fails for `A4|B4|A4|B5|C5`, printing nothing.